# python join different days dataframes with different timestamps and same column names

Tags: python, dataframe

I have data coming from different 26 power plants and sunlight sensors data in the field. Each sensor creates a data frame for a day. I have data of 14 days. So, I actually have 26x14=364 individual dataframes.  Finally, I want to combine all of them into one. Below I have given a sample data:

```
## Data coming in form of dataframes from field sensors 
sundf
ptA_d1df ### PlantA_Day1Dataframe
ptB_d1df
ptA_d2df
ptB_d2df
ptA_d3df
ptB_d3df

dflist = [ptA_d1df, ptB_d1df,ptA_d2df,ptB_d2df,ptA_d3df,ptB_d3df]
```

Dataframes on a given day have different timestamps as given below

```
sundf = 
                          light
2019-01-10 07:35:00     500
2019-01-10 07:36:00     510
2019-01-10 07:37:00     520
2019-01-10 07:38:00     530
2019-01-10 07:39:00     540
2019-01-10 08:14:00     550
2019-01-10 08:15:00     560
2019-01-10 08:16:00     570
2019-01-10 08:17:00     580
2019-01-10 08:18:00     590
2019-01-21 07:34:00     600
2019-01-21 07:35:00     610
2019-01-21 07:36:00     620
2019-01-21 07:38:00     630
2019-01-21 07:39:00     640
2019-01-21 07:40:00     650
2019-01-21 08:14:00     660
2019-01-21 08:15:00     670
2019-01-21 08:16:00     680
2019-01-21 08:18:00     690
2019-01-21 08:19:00     700
2019-01-21 08:20:00     710

ptA_d1df =
                       A
2019-01-10 07:35:22   10
2019-01-10 08:15:17   20

ptB_d1df = 
                       B
2019-01-10 07:38:45   30
2019-01-10 08:18:57   40

ptA_d2df = 
                       A
2019-01-21 07:35:42   50
2019-01-21 08:15:17   60

ptB_d2df = 
                       B
2019-01-21 07:39:04   70
2019-01-21 08:19:22   80
```

I wanted to combine above into one dataframe such that each session wise data is grouped together. It means, data of both plants around 7.35 AM should be grouped into one timestamp, not two and, also, columns with the same name should be grouped into the same columns, not creating new columns.

My code is given below:

```
dflist = [ptA_d1df, ptB_d1df,ptA_d2df,ptB_d2df]
l=[] 
k1 = []
sundf.index = pd.to_datetime(sundf.index)
sundf['time']=sundf.index  
for i,x in enumerate(dflist): 
    k1=sundf.reindex(dflist[i].index,method='nearest')         `
    l.append(k1.join(dflist[i]).set_index('time').reindex(k1.index,method='nearest'))
combdf = pd.concat(l,1)
```

I got output with different timestamps and different columns as given below:

```
  datetime           light  A   B  light  A   B  light  A   B  light   A      B  
2019-01-10 07:35:22   500   10  NaN   ........................ ..
2019-01-10 07:38:45   NaN ......... 530  .  30 Nan.................... 
2019-01-10 08:15:17   560   20  Nan........................ 
2019-01-10 08:18:57   NaN ......... 590  . 40  Nan........................ 
2019-01-21 07:35:42   NaN .                      610   50 
2019-01-21 07:39:04                                             640      70
2019-01-21 08:15:17   
2019-01-21 08:19:22
```

I wanted an output something like given below:

```
combdf = 
  datetime            light  A   light   B  
2019-01-10 07:35:22   500   10   530    30
2019-01-10 08:15:17   560   20   590    40  
2019-01-21 07:35:42   610   50   640    70
2019-01-21 08:15:17   670   60   700    80
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to divide time into 5 minutes time frames:

```
import pandas as pd

sun = [['2019-01-10 07:35:00', 500], ['2019-01-10 08:15:00', 560],
       ['2019-01-21 07:35:00', 610], ['2019-01-21 08:15:00', 670]]
A = [['2019-01-10 07:36:22', 10], ['2019-01-10 08:15:17', 20],
     ['2019-01-21 07:35:42', 50], ['2019-01-21 08:15:17', 60]]

B = [['2019-01-10 07:35:27', 30], ['2019-01-10 08:15:17', 40],
     ['2019-01-21 07:35:22', 70], ['2019-01-21 08:17:37', 80]]
dfsun = pd.DataFrame(sun, columns=['date', 'light'])
dfa = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['date', 'A'])
dfb = pd.DataFrame(B, columns=['date', 'B'])
dfa['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfa['date']).dt.floor('5T')
dfb['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfb['date']).dt.floor('5T')
dfsun['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfsun['date'])

df = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, on='date', how="outer")
df = pd.merge(dfsun, df, on='date', how="right")
print(df)
```

Out[]:

```
                 date  light   A   B
0 2019-01-10 07:35:00    500  10  30
1 2019-01-10 08:15:00    560  20  40
2 2019-01-21 07:35:00    610  50  70
3 2019-01-21 08:15:00    670  60  80
```

In the case you have already data in csv files in format `'file_{day}_{sensor}.csv'` for example:`file_1_2.csv`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([],columns=['date'])
for day in range(1,15): # csvs :'file_{day}_{sensor}.csv'e.g:'file_1_2.csv'
       dfSensor=pd.DataFrame([],columns=['date'])
       for sensor in range(1,27):
              dfNew = pd.read_csv(f'file_{day}_{sensor}.csv', names=['date', 
sensor])
              dfNew['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfNew['date']).dt.floor('5T')
              dfSensor = pd.concat([dfSensor,dfNew])
       df = pd.merge(df, dfSensor, on='date', how="outer")
df = pd.merge(dfsun, df, on='date', how="right")
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer the question. I have each day 26 dataframes for 14 days. So, 26x14 = 364 dataframes. Each day has around 18 timestamps. So, could you modify above code for combining 364 dataframes data.

Comment: sure, how do you have these dataframes stored ? (csv or in memory in a list)

Comment: 364 csv files. Now, 364 dataframes stakced in a list as dflist in my above question.

Comment: 364csv files. Now 364 dataframes all stacked in a list.

Comment: If you have big data its not a good idea to store several datasets into memory. It's better to load and merge one by one.BTW OK.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a solution, by modifying the datetime columns:**

```
# convert all to datetime
dflist = [ptA_d1df, ptB_d1df,ptA_d2df,ptB_d2df]

# convert all to datetime
for df_use in dflist + [sundf]:
  df_use['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_use['date'])
  # discard seconds, overwrite if not important
  # if granularity is important: create a new column
  df_use['date'] = df_use['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

# set index for concatenating
for df_use in dflist:
  df_use.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# concat them
df_mix = pd.concat(dflist, sort=False)
df_mix.reset_index(drop=False,inplace=True)

# merge them with the main df
df_agg = sundf.merge(df_mix)

# ---------------------------
# Now that the df is aggregated, get values for each observation
#
# create a new column of modified dates (for grouping)
df_agg['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_agg['date'])
df_agg['date'] = df_agg['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')

# Create new lookup dfs 
df_agg_A = df_agg[['date','Light','Light_A']].dropna()
df_agg_A.rename(columns={'Light':'Light_at_A'},inplace=True)
df_agg_B = df_agg[['date','Light','Light_B']].dropna()
df_agg_B.rename(columns={'Light':'Light_at_B'},inplace=True)

df_final = pd.merge(df_agg_A, df_agg_B)

#   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -

            date  Light_at_A  Light_A  Light_at_B  Light_B
0  2019-01-10 07         500     10.0         530     30.0
1  2019-01-10 08         560     20.0         590     40.0
2  2019-01-21 07         610     50.0         640     70.0
3  2019-01-21 08         670     60.0         700     80.0
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer the question. I have each day 26 dataframes for 14 days. So, 26x14 = 364 dataframes. So, could you modify above code for combining 364 dataframes data. In above code, for instance: creating new lookup dfs.

Comment: The code should work, if you add all dataframes to the list `dflist`. _Try it and see what happens?_

Comment: You created something called `df_agg_A`. How to use it my case because I have 364 dataframes?

Comment: `df_agg` is the aggregated values + times of dates per second ***combined*** with the values from Plants A and B. You can add values for "`Light`" to `sundf` by concatenating. You can add values from A & B to the list `dflist`.

Comment: could you modify your code to count for 26 PV plants. In your code you, Plant-A and B only are present. I have data of 26 PV plants. I am failing to figure out how to execute it for 26 PV plants data.

Comment: [What to do if the question is too “do it for me?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140166/what-to-do-if-the-question-is-too-do-it-for-me)

Comment: Looks like! my beginner questions hurt you. Sorry about that. I am trying to learn Python by asking some questions.